# When you do something in Java like list.get(i++) is it getting the element at index i and then incrementing i?

Tags: java, int, operators

As the title states. In Java I'm wondering if i = 5 and I do list.get(i++) will it return me the item at index 5 and then increment i to 6, or will it give me the item at index 6?

Comment: did you just try creating a list and accessing it the way you questioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post-increment. So the first one. Item at 5, then `i` becomes `6` on the next line. A simple demonstration,

```
int i = 0;
System.out.println(i++);
System.out.println(i);
```

prints

```
0
1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 6th one use the below
`i++;
list.get(i);`